# Unix command line continuation

Tags: unix, line, continuations

I am running a command to create a new directory. I am putting the `\` at the 80th column and continuing onto the next line. The `\` is being treated as a space. I have confirmed that there is no space after the `\`.

```
sh mkdir /home/sadaqat/thisissuchalongfilenamethatIhavetocontinueitontotthenext\line
```

The directory name comes out like this:

```
thisissuchalongfilenamethatIhavetocontinueitontotthenext line
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be in the 80th position, just before the carriage return.  For those that aren't aware, the backslash takes away the special meaning to the shell of the character immediately following.  Try it earlier than the 80th position for the fun of it.  Just `\` immediately followed by a carriage return.

Technically that's just for readability and you don't really need to do it.  Just let it wrap.